# How to count number of occurrence of specify char in varchar

Tags: sql, oracle

Is this possible in (Oracle) SQL?

I have a varchar for example "This is varchar" and I want to count number of "i" (it's 2)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use `REGEXP_COUNT` function as below:

```
select  REGEXP_COUNT( 'This is varchar', 'i' ) from dual
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions145.htm) you can find more information about REGEXP_COUNT.

**[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/10bb5/9/0)**

Comment: Caveat: I'm not an Oracle developer. I'm sure this works very well for the example but I would take heed to the `REGEXP` part of function name; simply substituting in `'.'` in place of `'i'` might not do what one wants it to do.

Comment: @ta.speot.is but this `select  REGEXP_COUNT( 'This is varchar.', '[.]' ) from dual` will work :)

Answer (score 3):

You could remove all of the `i`s and check the length difference.

```
select length('This is varchar')
       - NVL(length(replace('This is varchar', 'i')) , 0)
from dual;
```

Comment: EDIT: Need to consider nulls: `select length('iii') - length(replace('iii','i')) from dual;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
LENGTH(varcharString) - LENGTH(REPLACE(varcharString, 'i', ''))
```